# How to pass DB resultset values in html page

Tags: java, html

I have a simple MVC application, using a java class, which will fetch DB result values. Now i want to pass these DB values in HTML. How can I do that?

I am using html5 as View part.

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.mvc.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import com.mvc.bean.HbBean;
    import com.mvc.util.DBConnection;


    public class HBDao 
    {

        public String FetchHBRecords(HbBean hb)
        {



            String Deviceid = hb.getNidevid();  //Keeping user entered values in temporary variables.

            Connection con = DBConnection.createConnection();           
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;


            try
            {
                pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT hbtimestamp,battvolt,eventtype01,eventdata01,eventtype02,eventdata02,sensordata2 "
                    +"FROM nidhb where nidevid=? ORDER  BY hbtimestamp ");
                pstmt.setString(1, Deviceid);
                resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery(); 

                resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery(); 


                while(resultSet.next()) // Until next row is present otherwise it return false
                {


                    int battvolt=resultSet.getInt("battvolt");
                    int eventtype01=resultSet.getInt("eventtype01");
                    int eventdata01=resultSet.getInt("eventdata01");
                    int eventtype02=resultSet.getInt("eventtype02");
                    int eventdata02=resultSet.getInt("eventdata02");
                    int sensordata2=resultSet.getInt("sensordata2");

                    // hb.setHbtimestamp(hbtimestamp);
                    hb.setBattvolt(battvolt);
                    hb.setEventtype01(eventtype01);
                    hb.setEventdata01(eventdata01);
                    hb.setEventtype02(eventtype02);
                    hb.setEventdata02(eventdata02);
                    hb.setSensordata2(sensordata2);




                } 
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return "Invalid user credentials"; // Just returning appropriate message otherwise
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use proper MVC framework where you can send this data through model to JSP and using JSP, you can create html5 page. OR use Ajax call to do so.

Comment: How to pass values from model to JSP??

Comment: Can you tell me which MVC framework are you using?

Comment: I am not using any framework its a simple MVC

Comment: Check this example: http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp

Comment: Also which web server you are trying to use?

Comment: I am using Tomcat V6

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned the  MVC framework you are working on, I assume you want a JSP specific solution.

Seeing the code, it seems you are getting values from backend and putting them in the Bean `HbBean`. And now you intend to use this bean in JSP.

However, there seems some issues in you code.

1. `FetchHBRecords()` function would always return a string `"Invalid user credentials"`. Have you mentioned any break condition for successful login ?
2. `HBDao` is a *DAO class* which tries to establish connection with the database and instantiates the *Bean class* `HbBean` within the `FetchHBRecords()` function. This way, scope of `hb` (which is an instance of HbBean) would get limited to this function only! You should better return the Bean class or generate HTML `FetchHBRecords()` itself

If you resolve these issue, you may proceed with two options.

**Option-1** Use Scriptlet and import the Bean class

```
<%@page import="com.javatpoint.HbBean"%>  

<%  
    // Assuming you have already set the Bean instance in request attribute
    HbBean bean = (HbBean)request.getAttribute("bean"); 

    out.print(bean.getBattvolt());
    out.print(bean.getEventtype01());
    out.print(bean.getEventdata01());  
%>
```

Detailed [Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp).

**Option-2** Use JSP Java Beans (recommended)

The `<jsp:useBean>` action declares a JavaBean for use in a JSP.
Along with `<jsp:useBean...>`, you can use `<jsp:getProperty/>` action to access get methods and `<jsp:setProperty/>` action to access set methods. Here is the full syntax:

```
<jsp:useBean id="id" class="bean's class" >
   <jsp:setProperty name="bean's id" property="property name"  
                    value="value"/>
   <jsp:getProperty name="bean's id" property="property name"/>
   ...........
</jsp:useBean>
```

Detailed [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ya Thanks But how to resolve issue 2 as you have mentioned,Please can you change the code & give

Answer (score 0):

The code that calls `FetchHBRecords(HbBean hb)` can extract the values from the `HbBean` object and generate HTML, or pass the values to a JSP for rendering.

Comment: From Java class, How to pass those db result set values to JSP

Comment: That depends on the MVC framework you are using. Generally, you need to forward the request to the JSP, having set your data as request attributes, so that the JSP can render its output as a response to the request.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good answer, But its from my practice

```
<jsp:useBean id="postserivce" lass="com.anoop.live_tech.services.PostService"></jsp:useBean>


<jsp:useBean id="post" class="com.anoop.live_tech.domain.Post"></jsp:useBean>
```

And using JSP tag

```
<%
  ArrayList list=(ArrayList)postserivce.getPosts();

%>
```

And its showing

```
<body>

 <%
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
 post=(Post)list.get(i);
 String uname=postserivce.getunameFromuId(post.getUserId());

%>

<table align="center"> 
<tr><td align="center">
<h2><%=post.getPostTitle() %></h2></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<h1><%=post.getPostSubject() %></h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<h3 align="right"><%=post.getPostDate() %></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<h4 align="right"><%=uname%></h4></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>------------------------------------------------------------</td>      </tr>
</table>



<%
  }
%>
```

Here class Post is my bean file.